# How to convert an object to an array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am creating a Rails 5.2 app.
In this app I let my users save their settings to a JSONB attribute.

The data is posted from an Android app and looks like this:

```
{"email"=>true, "alert"=>true, "push"=>true}
```

I need to save this data as an array into the database.
This is my desired outcome.

```
[{"email"=>true}, {"alert"=>true}, {"push"=>true}]
```

*I tried this:*

```
object = {"email"=>true, "alert"=>true, "push"=>true}
object.to_a
```

But it rendered:

```
[["email", true], ["alert", true], ["push", true]]
```

Comment: object_array =[] object_array << {"email"=>true, "alert"=>true, "push"=>true}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this using the to_a you have tried

```
object = {"email"=>true, "alert"=>true, "push"=>true}
result = object.to_a.map{ |b| [b].to_h }
```

Or

```
object = {"email"=>true, "alert"=>true, "push"=>true}
result = object.map{ |key, val| [[key, val]].to_h }
```

Comment: This works perfectly! Thank you! I now see that I need to filter this array even more. I only want to keep an object in the array if the value is true. This is the desired result:

['email', 'alert', 'push']

Comment: Oh you want to filter the result to only have the keys where the result is true? If thats the case, then `object.select{|key, val| val}.keys` This is assuming the values is always boolean

Comment: You could say `object.map { |key, val| { key => val } }`

Comment: yeah correct. skipped my mind.